# How to test search result via nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch.js to do some end-to-end tests. Now I want to check if a specific search results matches my expectation. The result looks like this:

```
<div id="results" role="list" class="ui list">
    <div role="listitem" class="item">
        <span><strong>Samp</strong>le One</span>
    </div>
    <div role="listitem" class="item multiple pointer ">
        <div class="ui accordion">
            <div class="title pointer">
                <span><strong>Samp</strong>le Subcategory</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content pointer">
                <div role="list" class="ui list">
                    <div role="listitem" class="item pointer">Sub 1</div>
                    <div role="listitem" class="item pointer">Sub 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="listitem" class="item pointer">
        <span><strong>Samp</strong>le Three</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

That means there are three results: *Sample One*, *Sample Subcategory* and *Sample Three*. The second one has also to subresults *Sub 1* and *Sub 2*

I did not find something like `getElements` and check the number and each value of the results elements. So I tried to use `getText` but I think that is the wrong way...

```
this.searchTest = function (browser) {
  browser.getText("#results", function(result) {
    // ???
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElements` does not exist, indeed. But you can use [`elements`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements) instead!

The following script gives you the number of results and the text content for each result:

```
module.exports = {
  'getElements': function (browser) {

    function getInfo(elements) {
      console.log('Number of results: ' + elements.value.length);

      elements.value.forEach(function (element) {
        browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function (res) {
          console.log('RESULT ' + element.ELEMENT + '\n', res.value);
        });
      });
    }

    browser
      .url('http://www.website.com/') // <--- Don't forget to change this!
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
      .elements('css selector', '#results > div[role="listitem"]', getInfo)
      .end();

  }
};
```